# Bootstrap navigation goes out from the page

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, mmenu

If I zoom in on my page, the navigation bar won't collapse, it just goes out of the page. And also on mobile in landscape view, it is the same problem.

I am using the jQuery mmenu plugin, but that's not causing it.

I upload a photo of the problem, but you can also [check my page in live](https://kemenyem.hu/).

[image]

I removed the mmenu plugin, but that wasn't the problem, so it did nothing. I also tried removing `nav-justified` class, but nothing.

```
<div class="site_navigation">
    <div class="navbar navbar-expand-md">
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#menu" aria-controls="menu" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            <span class="navbar-toggler-icon">
                <i class="fas fa-bars navbar_ikon"></i>
            </span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="menu">
            <ul class="navbar-nav nav-justified w-100 container mr-auto">

                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/1/barabas-terko" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Barabás térkő</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/6/barabas-terko/barabas-badacsony-terko">Barabás Badacsony térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/38/barabas-terko/barabas-elegante-granitko">Barabás Elegante gránitkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/8/barabas-terko/barabas-teglako">Barabás Téglakő</a> 
                                            </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item"><a href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/36/kerti-szegely" class="nav-link">Kerti szegély</a></li>


                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/3/semmelrock-terko" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Semmelrock térkő</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/30/semmelrock-terko/semmelrock-citytop-grande-kombi-terko">Semmelrock Citytop Grande Kombi térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/39/semmelrock-terko/semmelrock-perla-kombi-terko">Semmelrock Perla Kombi térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/34/semmelrock-terko/semmelrock-stella-kombi-terko">Semmelrock Stella Kombi térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/40/semmelrock-terko/semmelrock-umbriano-kombi-terko">Semmelrock Umbriano Kombi térkő</a> 
                                            </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/10/terko-meret-szerint" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Térkő méret szerint</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/15/terko-meret-szerint/10x20-cm-terko">10x20 cm térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/18/terko-meret-szerint/20x13-3-cm-terko">20x13,3 cm térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/19/terko-meret-szerint/vegyes-meretu-kombi-terko">Vegyes méretű, kombi térkő</a> 
                                            </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/20/terko-szin-szerint" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Térkő szín szerint</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/29/terko-szin-szerint/barna-fekete-terko">Barna-fekete térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/21/terko-szin-szerint/szurke-terko">Szürke térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/31/terko-szin-szerint/voros-terko">Vörös térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/28/terko-szin-szerint/voros-barna-terko">Vörös-barna térkő</a> 
                                            </div>
                    </li>


                    <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                    <a href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/9/terko-vastagsag-szerint" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" role="button" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Térkő vastagság szerint</a>
                        <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdown">
                                                    <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/11/terko-vastagsag-szerint/4-cm-vastag-terko">4 cm vastag térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/12/terko-vastagsag-szerint/5-cm-vastag-terko">5 cm vastag térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/13/terko-vastagsag-szerint/6-cm-vastag-terko">6 cm vastag térkő</a> 
                                            <a class="dropdown-item" href="https://kemenyem.hu/kategoria/14/terko-vastagsag-szerint/8-cm-vastag-terko">8 cm vastag térkő</a> 
                                            </div>
                    </li>

                                </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have no error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the total width of the **`li`** elements is exceeding it container upon a specific break-point, i suggest to add **`flex-wrap: wrap`** to the **`ul`** element which is the nav container so the exceeded elements will be pushed one row down :

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav {
    -ms-flex-direction: row;
    flex-direction: row;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
}
```

Comment: Do i have to use the media query also? Or just simple add the code without the query?

Comment: It depends, since i have not check the whole css, so i used the media query as per the inspected code

Answer (score 0):

> Add `flex-wrap: wrap` on `navbar-nav

```
 .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {
 .navbar-expand-md .navbar-nav {
    flex-wrap: wrap;
 }
}
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you additionally provided some commentary and not just a code snippet.